# sendPluginResult() not working in onActivityResult() - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I'm new to Cordova. I am creating a custom plug-in for video capture in Android for PhoneGap.In my `onActivityResult()`, I am getting the captured video. I added a callback inside `onActivityResult()` which is not working.

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        final Mediatest that = this;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode == cordova.getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) {
                uriVideo = data.getData();
                Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        uriVideo.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 that.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 0));


            }
        } else if (resultCode == cordova.getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
            uriVideo = null;
            Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

But when i added the callback method outside onActivityResult, it's working:

```
private void captureVideo(Long limit) {
        this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 0));
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, limit);
        cordova.setActivityResultCallback (this);
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
        this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, 0));

    }
```

The Toast

```
Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        uriVideo.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

is getting displayed but the callback is not working. I'm unable to track the issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280625/passing-onactivityresult-in-cordova

Comment: not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

When you call the plugin, first send a plugin result with `NO_RESULT` and set `KeepCallback` as true

```
private void captureVideo(Long limit) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, limit);
    cordova.setActivityResultCallback (this);
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);

    //Send a plugin result with NO_RESULT and set KeepCallback as true
    PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
    r.setKeepCallback(true);
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);

}
```

Then you should be able to call the `sendPluginResult()` from the `onActivityResult()`

Comment: Why? This makes no sense to me why this is, it is so counter intuitive and I've been unable to find documentation supporting this, but I see it in other plugins I'm trying to debug that are failing for unrelated reasons and it is very confusing.

Comment: Each plugin call has an id and that id is used to call the plugin callback, if you don't set keepCallback to true the callback id is lost and then you can't send the result later.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I was under the false impression that each call to a plugin can be given only one result. But it seems this model supports one request with the issuance of multiple callbacks with various reported states and data. So sending back one "NO_RESULT" in no way would imply that instance is complete? Thanks so much for your time to help clarify.

Comment: If you use `r.setKeepCallback(true);` the instance is not complete, if you use `r.setKeepCallback(false);` (or don't set it as it's the default value) then the instance is complete. It doesn't matter if you send a OK, ERROR or NO_RESULT status value, the type of the status will determine which callback to execute or no execute any callback (OK-> success, ERROR -> failure, NO_RESULT -> no callback)